How to move WordPress language folders up a level in Nginx Config
The url structure for our Wordpress blog is "https://www.example.com/blog/en/" where "en" is the language code. We want to edit the nginx config so that the url structure becomes "https://www.example.com/en/blog/" as we require the language code preceding "blog". How can we achieve this?
location /blog {
           root /var/www/html;
           index index.php;
           try_files $uri /blog/index.php?$args;

           location ~ (.+).php {
              root         /var/www/html;
              fastcgi_index  index.php;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php56-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
           }
        }


The nginx configuration can't change what URLs your WordPress creates to begin with. (On that level, you could only redirect from /blog/en/ to /en/blog/ first, and then rewrite the incoming request for /en/blog/ to /blog/en/ again internally - makes rather little sense.) This should be fixed on the WP side of things.
